# jQuery tab: load image when tab is shown / performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap

I write the following code : http://jsfiddle.net/prestashop/Mmj8G/

The goal is to load images in tab only when the tab is shown.

```
$('#myTab a').on('show', function (event) {
        var tab = event.target.hash;
        $('.js-lazy-tab',tab).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('original')).removeClass('js-lazy-tab');

        });


    });
```

Does it make sense for better performance? Images are cached in the browser?

Comment: This makes sense and the images are cached in the browser :)

Comment: it does makes sense (there's even a plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), the only thing, I would add a background image with a gif to indicate the image is loading, but it's just preference. And yes for cache